# problem on removing coins landing on tails

Tags: probability

I flip 4 fair coins and remove all of the coins the land on tails. I flip the rest of the coins again and then remove the coins that land on tails.  the probability that I have removed at least three coins is

My attempt: I did by working out all the possible cases which were almost 10 and finally got the answer of 189/256 after a long time. It seems very lengthy but I feel that there must be an easier way.
Well I saw a similar question asked here but it uses partition theorem which I don't know as yet cause I am still in high school.

Comment: Hint:  Imagine every coin is tossed twice, even those that are discarded after the first round.  a given coin survives your game iff it comes up heads two times in a row.

Comment: This question isn't "weird" at all.  Why would you even *think* that?  Scroll through a few dozen problems on this site and see if you still think yours is "weird."

Comment: Likely “weird” was just employed as clickbait.  Not sure why people would do that, because when I see clickbait I either skip it entirely or just drop in without reading to complain that clickbait is stupid, then leave. Guess which one I’m doing now.

Comment: Is it fine now? I thought it weird cause it took me 9 cases to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to do this, which works for any number, $N$, of fair coins is to imagine that we toss all the coins twice, even those which are discarded after the first round.  A given coin survives your game iff it comes up $H$ both times.

Say we have $N$ coins and we want to remove at least $k$ coins.

Since $HH$ is a probability $\frac 14$ event the answer we want is then just $$\sum_{i=0}^{N-k} \binom Ni\times \left( \frac 14\right)^i\times \left(\frac 34\right)^{N-i}$$

In your case, $N=4, k=3$ we get $$\binom 40\times \left( \frac 14\right)^0\times \left(\frac 34\right)^{4}+\binom 41\times \left( \frac 14\right)^1\times \left(\frac 34\right)^{3}=\frac {189}{256}$$ as you have already determined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.